# How to populate a foreign key in dependent entity in Entity Framework Core first code approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, c#-4.0, entity-framework-core

I am using code first in EF Core.

Now I want a 1-M relationship between Countries and Cities i.e. each country can have many cities so I did this.

```
public class Countries
{
    [Key]
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}

public class Cities
{
    [Key]
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }

    public Countries Countries { get; set; }

    //public List<Donor> Donors { get; set; }
}
```

but while populating seed data in cities I had to face this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Cities>().HasData(
                    new Cities { CityID= 1, CityName= "Abu Dhabi" ,  },
                     new Cities { CityID = 2, CityName = "Dubai"  ,  },
                      new Cities { CityID = 3, CityName = "Al-Ain", },
                       new Cities { CityID = 4, CityName = "Mussafah", },
                        new Cities { CityID = 5, CityName = "Shahama", }
                );
```

Now I don't understand how do I populate the FOREIGN KEY country in it?

Comment: Create the Country and then add Cities to the Country's navigation property? That's how I would do it in the application code. I assume it works the same way when seeding the database.

Comment: sorry, didn't get you? Countries entity I have already created but the thing is that Country will hold many cities hence the navigation of country in cities but my problem is that how do you this countries in cities? since i need to map each city to some country.

Comment: You seem to have the relationship backwards. This [tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) might help.

Comment: but according to the conventions here entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/… if I add the navigation property at one end only, then also it will create 1-M i.e. adding Countries navigation prop in Cities entity

Comment: This question needs  more details  and clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to fix the classes:

```
public class City
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

       public int CountryId{ get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(CountryId))]
        [InverseProperty("Cities")]
        public virtual Country Country{ get; set; }

    }
public class Country
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty(nameof(City.Country))]
        public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }

    }
```

Then you can init

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().HasData(
                    new Country { Id= 1, Name= "jkkl"}
);

modelBuilder.Entity<City>().HasData(
                    new City { ID= 1, Name= "Abu Dhabi" ,  CountryId=1 },
                     new City { ID = 2, Name = "Dubai", CountryId=1  },
                      new City{ID = 3, Name = "Al-Ain", CountryId=1 },
                       new City { ID = 4, Name = "Mussafah",CountryId=1  },
                        new City { ID = 5, Name = "Shahama",CountryId=1  }
                );
```

Comment: thanks but wondering why putting Cities in country? what would that achieve?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. I fixed it

Comment: great update, but still if I omit the CITY from countries entity, would that effect it? I think there's no need of that there, what do you say ?

Comment: I think you have to take as it is. Cities in Country make it one to many.

Comment: ok but according to the conventions here https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

if I add the navigation property at one end only, then also it will create 1-M i.e. adding Countries navigation prop in Cities entity.

Comment: Look at Convention 4

Comment: Yes, I did but my question is why won't the other conventions work for it? Is using convention a matter of choice or need?

Comment: What do you call "Convention"? Please tell what is the problem? Is it still not working?

Answer (score 0):

If you create the classes as Sergey shows, Country.Id and City.Id will be defined as int identity(1,1) primary key and City.CountryId will be defined as a foreign key referencing Country.Id by convention. When you save newly created domain objects, you don't need to worry about the key values. EF will take care of all that for you.

```
// No need to specify Id value, the db context takes care of that.
Country UK = new Country { Name = "United Kingdom" };

// No need to specify Id or Country Id values, the db context 
// takes care of that.
UK.Cities.Add(new City { Name = "London" });
UK.Cities.Add(new City { Name = "Manchester" });
UK.Cities.Add(new City { Name = "Liverpool" });

using(YourDbContext ctx = new YourDbContext()) {

    ctx.Countries.Add(UK);

    ctx.SaveChanges();

    // After you save the changes, the db context will update 
    // the domain objects' key values (the country's Id value, and the three 
    // cities' Id and CountryId values) automatically.    
}
```